# Verbs for "lexicography" and "cartography"

Tags: meaning

While I'm performing the act of being a lexicographer or a cartographer (I know that they are different trades/acts) what verbs describe what I'm doing?

For example lexicography is what is being performed, but how do you say something similar to *a diver dives* or *a fisherman fishes* when talking about lexicography and cartography, or in fact a *-graphy* in the general case?

edit:

Just had a thought.... I think the answer is *constructs*, this is based on my belief that *-graphy* means to draw together or build up.

Comment: @peter taylor Actually I'm looking for the general case really

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the answer is *constructs*, this is based on my belief that -graphy can include 'to draw together' or 'build up'.

Comment: You are incorrect about the English etymology of -graphy including 'draw together'/'build up'. Please see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I would say *mapping* for a cartographer.  It's not exactly correct, but if you need more precision, you will probably have some definition/explanation already.

There is no general case for '-graphy', because it just means "the study of".

Comment: does it really mean study of? Or does it mean the construction (drawing together) of? oooh that's the answer..... A ...grapher constructs. Ta...

Comment: @Preet: "Some of the words with this ending denote processes or styles of writing, drawing, or graphic representation, as brachygraphy, calligraphy, stenography, cryptography, lithography, photography. More commonly they are names of descriptive sciences, as geography, bibliography (cf. the Greek βιβλιογραϕία, which means the writing of books), astrography, cometography, petrography, selenography, etc. Hybrid formations with this ending are rare..." (OED) Short form: yes, 'study of'.

Comment: @Preet: In Greek, *graphô* = "write", *-graphia* = "- writing". The sense of *writing* can be extended to *describing* (from Latin *scribo*, "write").

Comment: @cerburus - I knew this - this was why  I was attempting to extend writing to drawing up to drawing together to making.

Answer (score 4):

The nearest you might get to describing what a lexicographer does is *lexiconize*, 'to compile a lexicon'. I don’t think there’s any existing equivalent describing what a cartographer does.

Answer (score 3):

To oversimplify, there is no existing single word for either of these. So the simplest way of saying them is:

- a lexicographer **makes word lists**.
- a cartographer **makes maps**.

Comment: A lexicographer does rather more than make word lists. In Johnson’s words, a lexicographer is 'a writer of dictionaries; a harmless drudge, that busies himself in tracing the original, and detailing the signification of words.'

Comment: @Barrie: ...therefore the weaselly intro 'To oversimplify...', which is what the OP is looking for, as simple an expression as possible for the verb.

Comment: Understood. I always like to get Johnson quote in whenever I can.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a verb with the same Latin root, a cartographer *charts*.

Etymology:

> [chart](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=chart&searchmode=none): 1570s, "map for the use of navigators," from M.Fr. charte "card, map," from L.L. charta "paper, card, map"
>
> [cartography](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cartography&searchmode=none): 1843, from Fr. cartographie, from M.L. carta (see card (n.)) + Fr. -graphie, from Gk. -graphein "to write, to draw"

Answer (score 2):

I fear you are making an incorrect assumption in your question - that there is "in fact a -graphy in the general case". In fact, there is no general case that covers all words ending in -**graphy** in English.

As English has developed, it has borrowed many components from other languages at different times. The Greeks, due to their influential philosophy and technology, were a rich source of language roots to the rest of Europe. This process has happened continually over the centuries, and in a variety of ways, for a variety of reasons.

In English we've borrowed the Greek root [**γράφειν**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%86%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BD) *graphein* "scratch, draw, write" as -[**graphy**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-graphy) via Latin -**graphia** then French -**graphie**. So we have old words like cartography to modern words like photography. Wikipedia has [a list of dozens of words ending in -**graphy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graphies), including for example:

Autobiography
Bibliography
Calligraphy
Cartography
Photography
Pornography
Radiography

...but these are so distinct in English meanings that there is really no common verb describing the action of a -**grapher**. A calligrapher *writes*, a cartographer *maps*, a photographer *photographs*, a pornographer *makes pornography*, a radiography *takes radiograms*.

The common element is "writing, art, recording, listing, or a field of study". But I don't believe you'll find a single English verb that covers all that clearly.

---

By the way, in your answer you list **construct** from "draw together" as one of the meanings. This is incorrect in two ways. First, -**graphy** does not refer to construction except inasmuch as it refers to art or drawing. Second, you are confusing two senses of the English verb **[draw](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw#Verb)**: one meaning is "to depict with lines"; another is "to pull". **Draw together** comes from the "pull" sense, not the "depict" sense.

Comment: Thanks Mark this is a very good reasoned arguement. However looking at the examples - what is a photo-graph. It's a contruction of visual image, what is a radio-graph - it's a contruction of a radio picture or depiction. And the same I feel could be said about the others. I feel in the general sense the scratch/draw/write etymology is being taken too literally. As the language has evolved we've extended the meaning too - as I said in my question.

Comment: @PreetSangha I get your meaning, but I don't agree that 'construct' is a useful way to think of '-graphy', unless you are simply using 'construct' to mean 'make'. It's highly unusual to refer to a picture as being 'constructed'.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that -graphers *draft* things, in the sense of *[drafting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drafting)*:

- to draw the outlines or plan of; sketch.
- to draw up in written form; compose.

This is a more specific sense than simply making or creating things; it implies a skill and a gathering together in a way that make, create, and construct do not.

Comment: Well, a pornographer and a photographer don't really *draft* anything.

Comment: @Mark Maybe so, but OP asked about lexicographers and cartographers, and I feel *drafting* is suitable to describe the actions performed by both of these professions.

Comment: OP also asked about "-graphy in the general case"

Answer (score 1):

Why should *lexicograph* or *cartograph* not be a verb? I could take a photograph of something or I could photograph something. Unless you could lexicograph, how could you be a lexicographer?

Comment: I agree that if *lexicograph* were a noun it could probably be turned into a verb (or vice versa); but it's neither, any more than *geograph* is.  The reasons for this might make a separate question.  My own view, FWIW, is that just because a root word exists (*lexicography*) does not automatically create all related words: what would a lexicograph look like?

Comment: @TimLymington Ergo: cartograph(y) and lexicograph(y) do not belong together. One is a noun and a possible verb, the other is neither.

Comment: No. *Ergo* (since OP asked about both words), neither can be used to coin verbs. You may wish to make a point about cartography, but please don't misuse the rules of argument. (And in my view, a *cartograph would be called a map.)

Answer (score -1):

A cartographer *surveys* the land.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. The answers posted here should, if not answer the whole question, at least improve on other answers. Since this neither answers the whole question nor improves on other answers, I have down voted it. You might find your time better spent if you answer questions that do not already have ample answers.

Comment: @MattЭллен, ample answers is not the issue, rather correct ones. You might find better use of your time if you valued quality over quantity. I appreciate the warm welcome.